# CRM Script Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

When my Lead or Account or Contact form is loaded, what my client does that he clicks on sidebars link of these records.

Sidebar links as 'Notes & Attachments', 'Activities' etc.

Clicking on the sidebar links before form is getting loaded properly, it throws script errors.

Script errors are like:

1. 'Mscrm.Details' is null or not an object.
2. 'null' is null or not an object.
3. Out of memory.
4. 'Mscrm' is undefined.

Can we have any alternate idea so that these error will not should reproduce?

Any idea about disabling the 'Sidebar Links' till form gets fully loaded?

Anything that we can do about these errors?

Or one and last option that we should wait till form gets fully loaded?

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: if you think it's a client side issue, then try the IE dev tool bar; if you think it's server side, do not be afraid to attach VS to w3wp and catch first pass exceptions.  You can also turn on tracing and dig through the tracing files for helpful phrases to google.

Comment: I currently have a support ticket open with MS for the same exact issue. I'll post more once we close the ticket.

Answer (score 1):

1) you installed the RTM version and didn't apply any updates (rollup), in the first rollups this kind of errors was common

2) you are using an unsupported browser (IE9 or IE10) depending on your rollup version, need to check if you added the site in the compatibility mode list.

3) there are some unsupported customization (javascript code inside the form) that make the form to throw that error

Comment: 1) My CRM is online, updated 'Dec-12' and it will update again in 
'Dec-13'.

2) I am using Outlook for CRM. Developing in IE.

3)This may be the problem, i will first disable all my custom code.then i will retest for this error.